# Java unmarshilling JSON data containg abstract type

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, abstract-class

We are using Jersey/Jackson to unmarshall JSON data to java DTOs. One of my DTO is an abstract class, and i would like to unmarshall the JSON data to one of his extended DTO. For example, assuming i have these DTOs :

```
public abstract class AnimalDTO{}

public class DogDTO extends AnimalDTO{}

public class CatDTO extends AnimalDTO{}
```

I would like to unmarshall this JSON data:

```
{Zoo: {Animals:[{"type"="DogDTO", "code"="001", "name"="chihuahua"}, {"type"="CatDTO", "code"="002", "name"="felix"}]}}
```

As "type" would give the type of DTO i would like to unmarshall to. But it seems that this property isn't considered. Is there something I missed, or mistook in the JSON syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Instead of Zoo and Animals you should have "Zoo" and "Animals". In JSON we have "propertyName":"propertyValue" not a "propertyName"="propertyValue". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON Is it really looks like this?

Answer (score 10):

In your case you should use [`@JsonTypeInfo`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html) annotation.

For more information, please see below links:

- [JacksonFAQ](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ).
- [Jackson 1.5: Polymorphic Type Handling, first steps](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html).

Using above links I have created a simple example which serialize POJO objects with class names:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DogDTO dog = new DogDTO();
        dog.setCode("001");
        dog.setName("chihuahua");

        CatDTO cat = new CatDTO();
        cat.setCode("002");
        cat.setName("felix");

        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
        zoo.setAnimals(new AnimalDTO[] { dog, cat });

        Data data = new Data();
        data.setZoo(zoo);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        objectMapper.writeValue(writer, data);
        System.out.println(writer);
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
abstract class AnimalDTO {

    private String code;
    private String name;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AnimalDTO [code=" + code + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

class DogDTO extends AnimalDTO {
}

class CatDTO extends AnimalDTO {
}

class Zoo {

    @JsonProperty(value = "Animals")
    private AnimalDTO[] animals;

    public AnimalDTO[] getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

    public void setAnimals(AnimalDTO[] animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Zoo [animals=" + Arrays.toString(animals) + "]";
    }
}

class Data {

    @JsonProperty(value = "Zoo")
    private Zoo zoo;

    public Zoo getZoo() {
        return zoo;
    }

    public void setZoo(Zoo zoo) {
        this.zoo = zoo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [zoo=" + zoo + "]";
    }
}
```

This program prints:

```
{"Zoo":{"Animals":[{"type":"DogDTO","code":"001","name":"chihuahua"},{"type":"CatDTO","code":"002","name":"felix"}]}}
```

Comment: @GhostCat, I try to help as much as I can and encourage other to use these great tools like `Jackson` and `Gson` and make `JSON` simpler for others. I agree, it looks like niche but it is not intentional - I am just do not have to many time for other tags ;)