# Alternate solution to save as JSON datatype in postgres spring-boot + eclipselink

Tags: json, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

I am using eclipselink 2.6 with spring-boot JPA for persistance in postgres.

I am persisting a List of objects as a JSON column in database.Acording to this solution:  [eclipselink + @convert(json) + postgres + list property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149167/eclipselink-convertjson-postgres-list-property?answertab=votes#tab-top) 
I am able to save the data in postgres.

When the column is null, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "sample_column" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I can solve this issue by this answer:

[Writing to JSON column of Postgres database using Spring / JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238508/writing-to-json-column-of-postgres-database-using-spring-jpa?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Q1: Is there an alternate solution other than setting this property `stringtype=unspecified` int url `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbnam‌​e?stringtype=unspeci‌​fied` 

Q2: If not, How can I set `stringtype=unspecified` in application.prooerties of spring-boot rather than embedding it in the `spring.datasource.url`

Comment: Regarding Q2, you have already set stringtype=unspecified in application.prooerties ? What else you are looking for ?

Comment: What spring-boot version are you using?

Comment: spring-boot 1.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **spring-boot 1.4.1** or above,

add a **data.sql** file in resources folder,
`-- IN H2 database, create a column as 'OTHER' data type, 
 -- if H2 fails to create a column as 'JSON' data type.`
**`CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS JSON AS OTHER;`**

This .sql file will be executed during startup of your application and will create a column with data type **`others`** in table for the **'json'** data type columns in H2 database.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, but is implementation-specific.

For example, in Tomcat, this attribute is called `connectionProperties`, you would therefore write:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties: stringtype=unspecified
```

From [the Spring-Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database).

> It is also possible to fine-tune implementation-specific settings using their respective prefix (spring.datasource.tomcat.*, spring.datasource.hikari.*, spring.datasource.dbcp.* and spring.datasource.dbcp2.*). Refer to the documentation of the connection pool implementation you are using for more details.